# Jquery UI Droppable revert cannot drop again

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I have been trying to create a drag and drop system for a word learning application and have run into a problem with the draggable elements not being able to be reused after I revert the and try to drag them again.

To revert the draggable object I used the out method so that when you drag it back out of the droppable area it will revert back to its previous location.
I did this by removing the draggable instance and adding it back in, if I try to drag that same element back to the droppable area it wont be able to drop. I have tested with trying to reinitialise the droppable area also but that doesn't seem to change anything.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  createDraggable();
  createDroppable();
});

function createDraggable(){
  $(".word").draggable({
    containment: ".stage",
    revert: 'invalid',
    revertDuration: 0
  });
}

function disableOtherDraggable(except){
  $(".word:not(#" + except.attr('id') + ")").draggable('disable');
}

function createDroppable(){
  $('.drop').droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    accept: '.word',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.position({
        my: "center",
        at: "center",
        of: $(this),
        using: function(pos) {
          $(this).animate(pos, 200, "linear");
        }
      });
      $(ui.draggable).css('background', "transparent");
      disableOtherDraggable(ui.draggable);
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.mouseup(function () {
        ui.draggable.removeAttr('style');
        $(".word").draggable("destroy");
        createDraggable();
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I want to be able to let people drop the words and drag them back out if need be. I am going to set up a button to check the dropped word is correct after I get this working.

There are 4 words that can be dragged on this example but it can range from 3 to 5

***Update***

Here is the updated code that I got working for anyone interested. I created the stage as a droppable area and just toggled that on and off as needed.

```js
$(function() {
  function createDraggable(o) {
    o.draggable({
      containment: ".stage",
      revert: 'invalid',
      revertDuration: 0
    });
  }

  function toggleOtherDraggable() {
    $(".words .word").each(function(i, val){
     if(!$(val).hasClass('ui-dropped')) $(val).draggable('disable');
    });
  }

  function createLineDroppable(){
    $('.drop').droppable({
      tolerance: 'touch',
      accept: '.word',
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.position({
          my: "center",
          at: "center",
          of: $(this),
          using: function(pos) {
            $(this).animate(pos, 200, "linear");
          }
        });
        $(ui.draggable).css('background', 'transparent');
        $(ui.draggable).addClass('ui-dropped');
        toggleOtherDraggable();
      },
      out: function(){
        $('#stage-drop').droppable('enable');
      }
    });
  }

  function createStageDroppable() {
    $('#stage-drop').droppable({
      tolerance: 'touch',
      accept: '.word',
      disabled: true,
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).css('left', '0');
        $(ui.draggable).css('top', '0');
        $(ui.draggable).css('background', '');
        $(ui.draggable).removeClass('ui-dropped');
        $('#stage-drop').droppable('disable');
        $(".words .word").draggable('enable');
      }
    });
  }

  createDraggable($(".words .word"));
  createLineDroppable();
  createStageDroppable();
});
```

Comment: I feel this may have something to do with revert: 'invalid'. It may be seeing that word as invalid when I try to drop it a second time, just not sure why the class hasn't changed so it should still accept it.

Comment: can you show your HTML code also ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I do not see where the drpped item is appended to the new space. I suspect that your disabling function is being greedy and disabling too much since the dropped item is not where it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a location to drop a `.word`, one where you want to disable the others, and one to return to.

Consider the following example:

```js
$(function() {
  function createDraggable(o) {
    o.draggable({
      containment: ".stage"
    });
  }

  function toggleOtherDraggable() {
    if ($(".words .word").eq(0).hasClass("ui-draggable-disabled")) {
      $(".words .word").draggable('enable');
    } else {
      $(".words .word").draggable('disable');
    }
  }

  function createDropWord() {
    $(".words").droppable({
      tolerance: 'touch',
      accept: '.word',
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        var item = ui.draggable;
        item.removeAttr("style");
        $(this).append(item);
      }
    });
  }

  function createDropStage() {
    $('.drop').droppable({
      tolerance: 'touch',
      accept: '.word',
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        var item = ui.draggable;
        item.appendTo(this).position({
          my: "center",
          at: "center",
          of: $(this),
          using: function(pos) {
            $(this).animate(pos, 200, "linear");
          }
        }).css('background', "transparent");
        toggleOtherDraggable();
        createDropWord()
      },
      out: function() {
        toggleOtherDraggable();
      }
    });
  }

  createDraggable($(".words > .word"));
  createDropStage();
});
```

```css
.word {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .25em;
}

.drop {
  width: 340px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #CCC;
  margin: 20px;
}

.word.ui-draggable-disabled {
  opacity: 0.45;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="stage">
  <div class="ui-widget words">
    <div id="word-1" class="word ui-widget-content">Word 1</div>
    <div id="word-2" class="word ui-widget-content">Word 2</div>
    <div id="word-3" class="word ui-widget-content">Word 3</div>
    <div id="word-4" class="word ui-widget-content">Word 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="drop"></div>
</div>
```

When you first Drag and Drop to the `.drop` area, this will center the dropped object and also disable the other draggables, so they cannot be dragged in. When the item is dragged out, they are re-enabled.

You must use `.append()` or `.appendTo()` so that the item that is dropped is then added to the container. This applies to both elements.

The `revert` option is only enabled under specific drop circumstances. If the droppable will not accept the item or returns `false`, then the item is reverted when `invalid` is the preference.

Comment: I used the idea for having the stage droppable to put the word back to its original spot. I didn't append when moving the drop because it was making my dom jump about weirdly. I have added the updated code to my question for anyone else looking for information.